# Cy.get().type() does not seem to be registering as a keyboard event

Tags: cypress

I'm new to cypress. I'm using **cy.get('xpath to selector').type('something')** to fill in a field that works fine. The issue I'm having is filling the field should enable a continue button but it's not. It enables if I manually type in the field. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can first `click()` and then type.

```js
cy.get('xpath to selector').click().type('something')
```

Or, you can use `{force: true}`, it forces the action and disables waiting for actionability.

```js
cy.get('xpath to selector').type('something', {force: true}).type(‘{enter}’)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I tried both options. They do work as far as typing in the input but it still won't trigger enabling the button.

Comment: Can you share your html dom ?

Comment: Or on second thoughts how about you write `.type(‘{enter}’)` after type and see if that works. This will simulate the enter button key press.

Comment: Still nothing. I checked the event listeners on the input and tried triggering them but it's still not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just need to trigger the change event, since there is a side-effect happening (enabling the button).

Perhaps one of these

```js
cy.get('selector').type('something').trigger('change')
cy.get('selector').type('something').trigger('input')     // or this event
```

less likely, you would notice if needed

```js
cy.get('selector').type('something{enter}')
cy.get('selector').type('something').blur()    // aka tab off
```

Also possible validation slows down button enable, so next step in the test executes too fast.

```js
cy.get('selector').type('something').trigger('change')
cy.get('button').should('be.enabled')    // wait explicitly for enabled
```

One more guess

```js
cy.get('form').submit()   // try the form submit
```

Comment: Thanks Electron. I tried your suggestions but it's still not enabling the button needed to continue.

Comment: More stabbing in the dark - does `cy.get('form').submit()` do it? (The input will likely be within a form)

Comment: Otherwise, do you have a way to find what causes the button to be enabled?

Comment: any luck finding the solution?